# Supressing the paranthesis in natbib package

Tags: citing, natbib

I am currently using this package for citation. I just need the citation number as superscript, but it also comes with the paranthesis. Is there any way i can supress these parantheses.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super}


\begin{document}
$\beta$-protein\cite{hardy1992alzheimer}  % citation 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

reference.bib

```
@article{hardy1992alzheimer,
  title={Alzheimer's disease: the amyloid cascade hypothesis},
  author={Hardy, John A and Higgins, Gerald A},
  journal={Science},
  volume={256},
  number={5054},
  pages={184--186},
  year={1992},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

Comment: (1) welcome to the site, (2) it is custom here to provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is as that makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: @daleif Updated

Comment: Nice, will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\setcitestyle{%
  super,%
  open=,%
  close=,%
}
```

note the `%`, they are very important, `\setcitestyle` seems to not like spaces at all. There is still a small space from `protein` to the equivalent of `\textsuperscript{1}` that I have no idea where comes from.

BTW: Probably a better idea to use `unsrtnat` to be fully compatible with `natbib`

Comment: Thank you @daleif